# What is said about wearing a Tallit Katan night?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, tzitzis, sleep, evening-night, tallit-katan

Many questions here have been centered on the halachot if wearing a Tallit katan at night. My question take a a different approach. I have heard that Kabbalah speaks about the benefit of wearing a Tallit katan to sleep. What is actually said? Are there other sources that speak highly of this practice?

Answer (score 3):

Mishna Berura 21:15

> שלא לשכב - ובכתבי האר"י ז"ל כתוב ע"פ הסוד שיש לשכב בלילה בטלית קטן

> To not sleep - And in the writings of the Arizal it is written based on the mystical teaching [Kabbalah] that one should sleep at night while wearing a Tallit Kattan.

Comment: Thanks! There surely must be more regarding what the Arizal says though, right?

Comment: See Ariza”l Shaar Hakavonot, Derushei Leilah 1; Pri Eitz Chaim, Shaar Tzitzit 1.  See also Magen Avraham https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.21.2?lang=bi

Comment: As stated in the footnote here -https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3700205/jewish/Why-Sleep-With-Tzitzit.htm#footnote13a3700205

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this website on the Shulchan Aruch HaRav [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/tzitzis-at-night/#ftnref40):

> The scrupulous are particular to sleep with a Tallis Katan.<sup>1</sup> The Arizal severely warned that one is to wear the Tallis Katan at all times, even at night.<sup>2</sup> Practically, the custom of Chassidim is to be careful to sleep with a Tallis Katan.<sup>3</sup> One may even initially put on the Tzitzis at night for this purpose.<sup>4</sup>
>
> Segulos: Sleeping with Tzitzis is a Segula to be saved from impurities and evil spirits.<sup>5</sup> It is a great form of protection for the body and soul.<sup>6</sup> Wearing a Tallis Katan helps reduce inner fear that one may experience.<sup>7</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup> Siddur Admur “The scrupulous are accustomed to sleep with a Tallis”; [Ketzos Hashulchan 7/7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7720&st=&pgnum=43&hilite=); [Darkei Chaim Veshalom 38](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4692&st=&pgnum=34&hilite=)
>
> The reason: One is to sleep with a Tallis Katan in order so 1) If he awakens after daybreak he will not be unclothed without Mitzvos. 2) So he not need to place the Tallis Katan on prior to washing hands, and thus transgress the holiness of the Zohar, as explained in the laws of Hashkamas Haboker. 3) Based on Kabala, there is a Mitzvah to wear a Tallis Katan also at night. [Siddur ibid]
>
> <sup>2</sup> Arizal in Shaar Hakavanos Derush Arvis “One must be very careful not to remove the Tallis Katan. Not by day or by night”; [Peri Eitz Chaim Shaar Hatzitzis 1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49521&st=&pgnum=32&hilite=) “Do not remove the Tallis Katan at any time, even when sleeping, with exception to the bathhouse.”
>
> <sup>3</sup> See Igros Kodesh 13/29; 18/436 “Regarding what you write in my name of leniencies regarding sleeping with a Tallis Katan at night, I do not recall ever having said such things.” See Shulchan Menachem 1/40-41
>
> <sup>4</sup> Siddur Admur
>
> The reason: Doing so does not involve the prohibition of Baal Tosif being that there are opinions that state one is obligated to wear Tzitzis on a day garment even if it is worn at night. [Siddur ibid]
>
> <sup>5</sup> [Or Tzadikim 26/11](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31294&st=&pgnum=69&hilite=); Chida in [Tziparon Shamir 8/20](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32588&st=&pgnum=42&hilite=) (in the linked version it is letter vav); Shaar Hakavanos p. 52b
>
> <sup>6</sup> [Mishmeres Shalom 3/5](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8944&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=)
>
> <sup>7</sup>  Likkutei Sichos 33/273 [printed in Shulchan Menachem 1/41]